# QGIS: Saving TIF as Geopackage raster loses NoData cells

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, geopackage

**Background:**

At 3.8.3, I right-click a TIF DEM (single-band, 32-bit floating point) and **Export > Save As** to a Geopackage raster.

If I use all default settings in the **Export > Save As** window, the target raster is identical to the source TIF.  I am happy.

**Problem:**

However, if I select the *Pyramids* option in the **Export > Save As** window (with External GTiff .ovr, cubic resampling), the NoData values in the input TIF  are incorrectly set to the value **-999999.1** in the output Geopackage.  I am sad.

I also tried to force NoData output by checking the *NoData* option (screenshot below) and inserting a range that would encompass the -999999.1 range.  No difference.

**Workaround:**

If I Export without the *Pyramids* option, then run the **Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Overviews** tool, the resulting NoData cells correctly remain as NoData.  I am happy.

**Question:**

Is the NoData -> -999999.1 output normal, or (as I suspect) is this a bug in the **Export > Save As** window?

[image]

Comment: Seems like expected result to me, typically filter out the "No data values" for displaying on a map -- what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: This is not the expected result.  As I mentioned in the OP, the output NoData cells should be *NoData*; instead they are assigned the value *-999999.1*

Comment: What is the value assigned to NoData in the input raster?

Comment: The input NoData cells are assigned to NoData.  I'll edit the OP accordingly.  Thanks, this edit will make the OP make better sense.

Comment: My understanding of raster files may not be correct, but I believe that a numerical value is stored in all pixels. Then, one value can be assigned to the NoData tag, so that the programs that represent the raster interpret, each time they read that value, the "non-existence of data". But the input raster must have a numerical value stored in that pixels, and that numerical value assigned to NoData.